# How can I style many layers of vector grid once in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, vector-grid

After I created many of vector grid layers, I now need to style them in a batch system. Is there any way to do this?

If that is not possible, how can I use the layer duplicate option to inherit the style from the original grid; and then change the extents of the duplicated layer?

Comment: What you mean by "change the extents"?

Comment: @mapsir When you create a polygon vector grid, you have to assign the extents, then after you save the layer, you can't change the extents using the properties of the layer, is that possible?

Comment: In QGIS when you add more features to a shapefile, it automatically calculate and set the extents.

Comment: @mapsir I need to change the extents, not adding more features.

Comment: In a web application you can set a desired extent for viewing a vector, but I think we can not change the extent of a vector layer in QGIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to **batch style** your layers you may select the source layer, right click on it and choose `Copy Style`.

Then select your target layers keeping the `Ctrl` key pressed.

Eventually, go to the `Layer` menu and choose `Paste style`.

I've noticed that the `Paste style` menu is activated only when the target layers are similar to the source layer.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

You can easily paste your copied style in a text editor, using `Ctrl+V` to study it.

Or you can save the initial layer style in the `.qml` or `.sld` file format, in a separate folder called `QGIS styles`, for example.

Then, when you create a new layer, just browse the `QGIS styles` folder for a convenient style. This way, *styling* will become an integrated part in the *new layer creating process*.

A better approach, especially in a medium with more developers involved, you can save/load your `layers' styles` directly in/from the database:

[image]